# syntax of python IN operator

Tags: python, syntax, logic

just starting to learn python I'm picking up on it pretty easily, but then I came to the IN operator, the site I'm using shows the code set up in a way that I cannot get to work, I have searched the internet and stack but haven't come up with anything solid, the way they have it written makes me believe that you could check a list for more than one variable with this statement.

```
if name in ["John", "Rick"]:
    print "Your name is either John or Rick."
```

but I have yet to find an equivelent anywhere else on the internet, the online IDE on the site doesn't give me a syntax error for this but it always returns false no matter what I have in the list: name.

so my question is: Is the above code valid python? and if so what would make it return **true**?

Comment: Well, your code works for me.

Comment: can you post the code you used to test it?

Comment: Insert  `print repr(name)` immediately before this `if` statement, run the program again, and show us what it prints, please.

Comment: First define `name` like `name = "John"` or `name = 'Rick'`, and then run your code, it print `Your name is either John or Rick.`

Comment: if I use this code, it always prints else

name = ["John", "Rick" ,"tim", "george"]

    if name in ["John", "Rick"]:
        print "Your name is either John or Rick."
    else:
        print "else"

@zwol with your edit it prints
['John', 'Rick', 'tim', 'george']
else

Comment: @KevinGuan if I make name a single string instead of a list then it works. So does that mean I cant use the IN operator on a list?

Comment: `name` isn't a name. It's a `list` of multiple names. If you want to use code like the block you gave, `name` should be a name.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a `list` is and what `in` does. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: thank you! I will check out that link to see what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `name` as a list as you said in comments, so here's what Python does:

```
>>> name = ["John", "Rick" ,"tim", "george"] 
>>> name in ["John", "Rick"]
False
>>> name in ["John", "Rick", ["John", "Rick" ,"tim", "george"]]
True
>>>
```

`x in y` only check **if there's a element *called* `x` in `y`**. **Not** check **if there's a element in `x` and it's also in `y`**.

That's why following code works but the above code doesn't:

```
>>> name = 'John'
>>> if name in ["John", "Rick"]:
...     print("Your name is either John or Rick.")
...     
... 
Your name is either John or Rick.
>>>
```

In this case you need:

```
>>> if any(i in ["John", "Rick"] for i in name):
...     print("Your name is either John or Rick.")
...     
... 
Your name is either John or Rick.
>>>
```